# Pick data from android SQL lite database and show it on home page

Tags: android

I'm using a "View All" button to display data from SQL Lite from database in `Datapicker`.java activity and now I want to show this data in home activity(`Mainactivity`.java) immediately after launching app(not by button clicking) instead of Datapicker.java. Here is the code in `Datapicker`.java

```
         case R.id.btnViewAll:
            Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM jaffa order by date asc", null);
            if(c.getCount()==0)
            {
                showMessage("Error", "No records found");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
            while(c.moveToNext())
            {
                buffer.append("Name: "+c.getString(0)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Occasion: "+c.getString(1)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Date: "+c.getString(2)+"\n"+"\n");

            }
            showMessage("Occasion Details", buffer.toString());
            break;


public void showMessage(String title,String message)
{
    Builder builder=new Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.show();
```

Comment: Do you just want to display it in a `ListView`?  What does your MainActivity look like?

Comment: yes, i want to display in listview. Mainactivity page has two buttons, these buttons take us to two other pages.